# How to show refresh message on browser window

Tags: asp.net, ajax, messagewindow

I have an asp.net application with Ajax in which I'm using update panel for a grid view for refreshing. I want to show the message on browsing  window saying "Refreshing in 30 seconds" (number vary for each second).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the asp:Timer Control inside an update panel.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the client in javascript with some good old fashioned DOM manipulation:

```
var count=30;
var interval=setInterval(function()
{
    var tn=document.createTextNode("Refreshing in "+count+"s"); 
    var targetElement=document.getElementById("someElemId");
    var replaceText=targetElement.childNodes[0];
    if(replaceText!=null)
    {
        targetElement.replaceChild(tn,replaceText);
    }
    else
    {
        targetElement.appendChild(tn);
    }
    if(count==0)
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
        window.location.reload(true); //or whatever you need to refresh
    }
    --count;

},1000);
```

You'll need some sort of element in the DOM with id "someElemId". Of course, setInterval isn't 100% accurate, but should be good enough.